# While creating a very large number of relationships neo4j keeps saying server is disconnected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a large amount of relationships to create using cypher and I keep getting the following error: `Connection to server lost. Reconnecting..`

Increased memory. Ran the query and neo was using ~37GB of memory, with the rest going to RAM cache/buffer. Diskspace and cpu usage seemed to be ok. Server keeps saying `Connection to server lost. Reconnecting..`

EXPLAIN 
MATCH (r:Room),
(t:Thread)
WHERE EXISTS (r.unique_room_id) AND EXISTS (t.unique_room_id) AND r.unique_room_id=t.unique_room_id
CREATE (r)-[:PUBLISHED]->(t);

Expected results would be to create millions of relationships. In the image below you can see the details behind how this query is being executed. Any suggestions? Thank you! [Query plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFBW9.png)

Comment: You will need to use apoc.periodic.iterate for batching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your server has correctly configured heap and page-cache.

You can use the [apoc library](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/) to batch this operation:

Presuming you have an index on `:Thread(unique_room_id)`

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate('
MATCH (r:Room)
WITH r.unique_room_id as unique_room_id
MATCH (t:Thread) WHERE t.unique_room_id = unique_room_id
RETURN t, r
','CREATE (r)-[:PUBLISHED]->(t)', {batchSize:100000});
```

see: http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/cypher-execution/commit-batching/